# Fastest way to parse large xls files with PHP

Tags: php, excel, laravel

So basically I'm trying to parse large xls/xlsx files in PHP (Laravel). The flow is a tad different than usual:

1. I need to grab the column headers from a specific row (provided by user) and return as array
2. I need to then parse xls file into an array
3. I need to iterate over the array, mapping the keys of each value to the column name (because input is variable and mysql columns aren't), so I'll change eg [someKey => value] to [item => value] every time
4. I then use Laravel's :insert() to batch insert the array into the database

This is basically an api, so it needs to be reasonably fast on eg 15k rows xls files. I tried two things so far, both having their issues:

1. [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/getting-started/) no way to grab just one row, it parses the entire file twice, once to return headers, and once to map the value keys
2. [Python openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which I'm calling from the Laravel controller with `exec()`, while being faster, seems somewhat harder to control, as the array map to specific keys gets a bit more complex.

Is there a better/faster way to do something like this? Laravel can't be changed, but everything else is fair game. I also have zero control over input files, but a user has to define the row containing headers.

This is running on a Digital Ocean droplet, LAMP stack, CPU Optimized Droplets, 4 GB / 2 vCPUs. It's running both front (React) and back (Laravel) on the same machine. What happens is CPU goes up to 100% immediately as I run the parse, which isn't a huge issue, since it's fairly stable, but I'm just looking for a possible better/faster way of doing this, specifically, a way to yank just one row so I return headers faster, and then maybe a better way to map column names in the array.

Comment: A colleague mentioned [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout) to me recently. I'll admit I didn't give it a try myself, but it seems it can parse large files with very low memory usage.

Comment: Thank you I'll definitely benchmark Spout for my use case and see how it holds up. I'm definitely toying with the idea of changing the col names directly in the xls file, so I don't have to iterate the entire array as well

Comment: For me the fastest way to do it was converting the xls to csv, it's much faster and you don't have to parse the whole file - you can parse by chunks.

Comment: Is there a specific converter that does it fast with large files I can use in PHP/call from PHP?